# How to display filtering model relations on a GridView

Tags: php, gridview, activerecord, yii, yii2

I have two tables:

- Country
- City

And have relations in model.

Why doesn't city have a filter?

```
public function getCountry()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Country::className(), ['id' => 'c_id']);
}
```

`GridView` image:

[image: GridView Image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply accessing it like:

```
'columns'=>[
   'country.columnName',
]);
```

In model override `attributes()` function:

```
public function attributes()
{
    // add related fields to searchable attributes
    return array_merge(parent::attributes(), ['country.columnName']);
}
```

Add it to rules:

```
public function rules()
{
     return [
         [['country.columnName'], 'safe'],
            // ... more stuff here
     ];
}
```

And in `search()` method, add this to your `Query`:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'country.columnName', $this->getAttribute('country.columnName')]);
```

================================ OR =================================

```
'columns' => [
   [
       'attribute' => 'countryFilter',
       'value' => function($model) {
           return $model->country->columnName;
        }
   ]
]);
```

To filter it, add custom property do your search class:

```
public $countryFilter;
```

Add this in rules:

```
public function rules()
{
     return [
         [['countryFilter'], 'safe'],
            // ... more stuff here
     ];
}
```

Add relation to `Query` in `search()` method:

```
->joinWith(['country'])
```

Then add filtering stuff to `Query`:

```
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'country.columnName', $this->countryFilter])
```

And to sort it, add:

```
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['countryFilter'] = [
                'asc'  => ['country.columnName' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['country.columnName' => SORT_DESC],
            ];
```

More information is available in docs: [Displaying & sorting relational data](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/)